# Compare current date with birthday in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've got the following code which works perfectly well other than one major flaw... It only works if the birthday/anniversary is the same year as current.

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query( "SELECT mFN, mSN, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, mBirthday, CURDATE()) 
    AS mAge, mBirthday FROM memberData WHERE mBirthday BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK" );
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo sprintf("%s %s will be %s on the %s. <br>", $rows['mFN'], $rows['mSN'], $rows['mAge'], $rows['mBirthday']);
}
```

So what this does is, compare current date + interval of a week with the birthday stored...

If someones birthday is on the 5th of march 2015, it'll find them!
Although if someones birthday is on the 5th of march 1995, no luck because of the year... any idea on how i would resolve this? quite new to programming and not sure how to tackle this.

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query( "SELECT mFN, mSN, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 
   STR_TO_DATE( concat(year(curdate()), '-', month(mBirthday), '-', day(mBirthday) ), '%Y-%m-%d' ) , CURDATE()) 
AS mAge, mBirthday FROM memberData 
WHERE 
   STR_TO_DATE( concat(year(curdate()), '-', month(mBirthday), '-', day(mBirthday) ), '%Y-%m-%d' )  
      BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo sprintf("%s %s will be %s on the %s. <br>", $rows['mFN'], $rows['mSN'], $rows['mAge'], $rows['mBirthday']);
}
?>
```

im gettinng Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, sprintf line.

Comment: There should be MySQL functions that return a day and month number for a datestamp, which you can compare - just ignore the year. You'd be looking for 5 and 3 respectively for a birthday on 5th March of any year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match on the `month()` and `day()` functions.  For example:

```
where month(CURDATE()) = month(yourdate) and day(curdate()) = day(yourdate)
```

You'll need to be careful on leap years though (feb 29).

To test against the date in the current year, you can use something like:

```
-- replace year in test date with current year
STR_TO_DATE( concat(year(curdate()), '-', month(mBirthday), '-', day(mBirthday) ), '%Y-%m-%d' )
```

Though it may be more efficient to store the month and day as separate fields in the database.

The final query looks something like:

```
SELECT mFN, mSN, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, mBirthday, CURDATE()) AS mAge, 
    mBirthday FROM memberData 
WHERE 
   STR_TO_DATE( concat(year(curdate()), '-', month(mBirthday), '-', day(mBirthday) ), '%Y-%m-%d' )  
      BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Here are alternative approaches:

[finding if an anniversary is coming up in n days in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874772/finding-if-an-anniversary-is-coming-up-in-n-days-in-mysql)

Comment: How would i implement this within my existing query?

Comment: Ah, you want the birthdays in the next week.    One approach... you can strip out the month and day from the test date, and replace year with the  current year.  Then convert back to a date with  STR_TO_DATE();  So you can test the curdate with the anniversary in the current year.  It might help to save the date as day, month, year.

Comment: WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK = MONTH(mBirthday) AND DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK = DAY(mBirthday)");  -- something along these lines? but this doesn't work.. any ideas?

Comment: I think the same query, but test against the date in the current year.. something like:  STR_TO_DATE( concat(year(curdate()), '-', month(mBirthday), '-', day(mBirthday) ), '%Y-%m-%d' )

Comment: sorry, im new to this.. how is that going to search a week in advance? what would the actual final query look like

Comment: It translates the birthday to their upcoming birthday.  So you are comparing the current date, to their birthday *this year*.  Since your query works for the current year, and all dates are translated to the current year, everything should work (assuming I didn't do a typo).

Comment: I added an example in the main post

Comment: getting t-string error, added to main, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the php is missing the closing "); on the query.

Comment: is there a way to change the date from y-m-d to d-m-y without ruining the query?

Comment: They can be in any order, but the format string '%Y-%m-%d'  used for parsing would need to match.